# Is it possible to store login for ssh servers?

Tags: linux, ssh, login

Would it be possible to store the login by default for ssh server in a configuration file?

I have plenty of server with different credentials. I am using the same ssh key for all of them, but I always forgot the login I need. Instead of writing:

```
$ ssh tbuser22@myserver.inc
```

I would like to use:

```
$ ssh myserver.inc
```

And it would use the login configured for that server. In the case I need to login with a different credentials, I still can manually at the `login@` prefix.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set this up by using `~/.ssh/config`. Create the file with the lines

```
Host myserver.inc
User tbuser22
```

You can have multiple host sections in the file. Other parameters can also be set on a per-host basis, like `IdentityFile`, and paramteres are in effect until the next Host line.

You can also have universal settings by having `Host *` as your last entry in the file and parameters set here apply to all hosts unless specifically overridden. When you have multiple Host lines, they are read in order and the first match is used. Wildcards can be used in defining the matched host. Thanks @user1686 for catching this.

Any command-line parameters will take priority over settings in the config file.

Comment: ssh_config uses the opposite order – individual host sections should go first, and the catch-all `Host *` should go last, as only the first instance of a parameter is used.